# Best Approach to Migrate from MySQL to SQL server on Live Environment

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, migration, live, sql-server-migration-assi

My client has a large MySQL database with about 5GB of data (15M records). They want to migrate to SQL Server 2008 R2.

What is the best Approach to Migrate from MySQL to SQL server on Live Environment?

Answer (score 0):

We have migrated the MYSQL Database with 1Gb of data previously .

We have used the **Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant v5.3 for MySQL** tool for this activity.

It is very helpful in migrating huge databases.

you can download it from [downloadLink](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42657) .

Step by step guide is mentioned in video [Step by step guide video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXe4XL41jVE)

*You should also change the jdbc drivers and the Database connection URLS on production*